# Why is this character called "The Prophet"?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, mirror-universe

In *Star Trek Discovery* [1x11 "The Wolf Inside"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Wolf_Inside_(episode)), we meet the Mirror Universe version of Sarek, who is called "The Prophet". Apparently he has this title because he can mind meld with people to discover their true intentions.

But the non-Terran alliance appears to consist of the entire Vulcan race, and there isn't any evidence that a select few Vulcans in the Mirror Universe can mind meld; Mirror Spock and Mirror T'Pol could do it on their shows. So why single out Sarek, or any other Vulcan, as "The Prophet"?

[image: Mirror Sarek]

<sub>*Of course Mirror Sarek has a goatee…*</sub>

Comment: Didn't *Enterprise* establish that it was a relatively rare ability, even in the Prime Universe?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Did it? I didn’t see all the episodes of that show, and was under the impression that it was something all Vulcans could do, since all the main character Vulcans could do it.

Comment: I believe that in *Enterprise* that mind-melding was considered a bad thing as it could cause mental imbalances (kind of a disease) by Vulcan society and those that practiced it were ostracised/forced to go underground. It seems more a cultural shift than an ability shift.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: As Jon said, *Enterprise* portrayed mind-melding as a taboo thing at first. In the 4th season, it was explained that "only some Vulcans can mind-meld" is a myth fabricated by the then oppressive Vulcan government.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you might be thinking the definition of the word "Prophet" requires him to see the future, when: "wise" and "teacher" are also in its meaning. His ability to mind-meld doesn't make him "wise" or a "teacher", I think he just has a special ability the rebellion enjoys when they need to fact-check imperial spies.

I think Star Trek has already confirmed that Sarek is "wise".